# How my mobile app knows I'm logged on server

Tags: android, spring, oauth, spring-security

how can I make my Android app recognized by the server as logged in a user account? I need send a token with every request, or there is a way to store some kind of Id of my device as logged?

I'm using Spring Security with Mvc and I got this trouble in my mind

An explanation would be very good, currently I have no code since it's a thinking thing.

Comment: The concept of "logged on" user typically means "user having a session" on the server. This concept still applies regardless what device / interface user is using. A user can be using mobile apps, browser, sms etc but they can still have a session with the server

Comment: Hmm nice, but on browser I have the JSESSIONID, what about on mobile? There's something similar?

Comment: Ofcourse. See http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/AbstractHttpMessage.html, JSESSIONID is just a cookie, which is just a HTTP response header which you can obtain using `getHeader`. I'm sure there are libraries which supports cookie by default

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will try to find out more about getHeader

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas: Not sure it will helpful for you or not, because i did this things for c#.net web api and android communication.just check, it may help you..

1st: you can write your own web service/web api to handle user authentication in server. Something like when you send email id and password to the server ,the web service will check it in database and if success then send you the generated Id or some data if you want. And if failure it will give you null/zero or some value to recognize the failure.

2nd: You can use your server cookies which will access by `getCookieStore().getCookies()`. You have also to write some server program to check if the user login  succeeded or not. If true then send the session variable/some generated cookie  inside it and handle it in android code.
if failure then cookies will be null.